# Inactividad en una o varias pestañas

Tags: angularjs

Estoy validando la inactividad del usuario en una pestaña, tengo un problema cuando el usuario abre mas de una pestaña del mismo programa ya que la inactividad se valida en todas las pestañas si el usuario abrió dos pestañas y trabaja solo en una , cuando el tiempo de inactividad de la segunda pestaña abierta termine el sistema cierra la sesión del usuario automáticamente.

Quisiera saber como validar la inactividad de las dos pestañas o en las que abra.

```
new Idle().whenNotInteractive().within(15).do(() =>
this.loginService.CerrarSesionInactividad().subscribe(
    result => {
      localStorage.removeItem('Data');
      if (!this.varlidarTiempo) {
        swal({
          title: 'Advertencia',
          text: '',
          html:
          'Tu cuenta ha estado inactiva por mas de <b>15 Minutos</b> se cerrara la sesión. ',
          type: 'warning',
          showCancelButton: false,
          confirmButtonText: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>  Salir',
          cancelButtonText: 'No',
          confirmButtonColor: 'rgb(13,165,80)',
          cancelButtonColor: 'rgb(160,0,87)',
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          allowEscapeKey: false
        }).then((results) => {
          if (results.value) {
            localStorage.removeItem('Data');
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/Login');
            this.varlidarTiempo = true;
            localStorage.clear();
          }
        });
      }
  })
).start();
```

Este el código que tengo en el momento y funciona perfectamente.
Me podrían ayudar o dar sugerencias para solucionarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que estás usando la librería [idlejs](https://github.com/harunurhan/idlejs).

Dicha librería puede gestionar la inactividad **y** la actividad, así que yo le daría la vuelta: mientras tengas actividad, no tienes que cerrar la sesión:

```
  const notIdle = new NotIdle()
  .whenInteractive()
  .within(5,1000)
  .do(() => sessionStorage.setItem('lastActivity',new Date().getTime()))
  .start();
```

Puesto que la información es accesible por todas las pestañas que compartan el mismo dominio, puedes tener un simple setInterval que lea ese valor, comprueba si la última actividad fue hace más de 15 minutos y, si es así, cerrar la sesión.

```
const LIMIT= 60000 * 15; //15 minutos

setInterval(() => {
  let la = new Date( +sessionStorage.getItem('lastActivity'));
  if (new Date().getTime() - la > LIMIT) {
     // ... cerrarSesión
  }
}, 60000); //comprobar cada minuto
```